# Unable to access JSON using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two JSON objects.  One JSON object is supposed to be providing me with a key for the second JSON object.
JSON 1 (tableInfo):

```
[
 -{
  name: "id",
  dataType: "Integer",
  isEditable: false
 }
 -{
  name: "article",
  dataType: "String",
  isEditable: true
 }
 -{
  name: "publisher",
  dataType: "String",
  isEditable: false
 }
-{
 name: "metadata.comments",
 dataType: "Integer",
 isEditable: false
 }
]
```

JSON 2 (currentInfo):

```
[
-{
 id: 0,
 article: "JavaScript Conquers the World",
 publisher: "Daily Times",
 metadata: {
      comments: 4
     }
 }
-{
 id: 1,
 article: "The Problem with Foobar",
 publisher: "New York Times",
 metadata: {
      comments: 27
     }
 }
]
```

I want to use a ng-repeat (or a similar directive) to display the information in JSON 2 as a table where the "name" from JSON 1 acts a column divider (e.g. |"id"|"article"|"publisher"|)

I know to get just the name feature of JSON 1 I could easily do a

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in tableInfo">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

But how would one access each property (item.name) of every element in JSON 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- item.name comes from the parent loop -->
<td ng-repeat="anotherItem in currentInfo">
    {{anotherItem[item.name]}}
</td>
```

Comment: I'm having troubles accessing metadata.comments with this method, but it definitely has helped me make progress.  Thanks!